# make random list, this list is on other archive python

Tags: python

I wanna get a list **random** from other list but i get this problem:  **TypeError**: object of type '**function**' has no `len()`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

def listaidcanciones():
        tree = ET.parse('Library.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        idsong = []
        for child in root.iter('id'):
                idsong.append(child.text) 
        return idsong
print(listaidcanciones())

import random
from accesodatos import listaidcanciones

def suicide(listaidcanciones):
    songsrandom = []
    for listaleatoria in listaidcanciones(range(1,len(listaidcanciones))):
        random.shuffle(listaleatoria)
        songsrandom.append(listaleatoria)
    return songsrandom
print(suicide(listaidcanciones))
```

Comment: Your parameter is the same name as your import. Rename it.

Comment: You ask for the len of `listaidcanciones` which is the name of your function. I guess you wanted to ask for the len of the result of the function : `listaidcanciones()`